# How to get url of uploaded file in Pods Framework 2?

Tags: php

I havve created a pod called **teams** and within this pod I created a field for uploading imagethat is called **team_flag**

I can echo the title of that row in a while loop, but not the file(image) link.

E.g. this code for title output is working nice:

```
<?php echo $teams->field( 'name' ); ?>
```

However, echoing link to the file is not:

```
<?php echo $teams->field( 'team_flag' ); ?>
```

Any advice how to fix it?

Comment: ok solved by myself: <?php echo $teams->field( 'team_flag.guid' ); ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION** is to add **guid** at the end:** `<?php echo $teams->field( 'team_flag.guid' ); ?>`

Answer (score 4):

The .guid is not a reliable property to use. If you migrate your site to another domain, all your URLs will break.

You should use

```
wp_get_attachment_url( $teams->field( 'team_flag.ID' ) )
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, @rclai89 is correct, it is better to use:

`wp_get_attachment_url( $teams->field( 'team_flag.ID' ) )`

For some new comers this might be a bit confusing.
What that line will do, is get the URL of the ID given from that field.

if you did a error log:

`error_log(print_r($teams->field( 'team_flag.ID' ),1 ));`

You can see why using .guid would give you the correct "url".

but it is best to let WP do the hard work in this case:

`<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $teams->field( 'team_flag.ID' ) ); ?>`

Will in fact be more efficient.